# Use HTTP PUT from an Sybase database to a REST API

Tags: sql, database, rest, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to update a website using a REST API. What I'd really like to be able to do is send a HTTP PUT request to the API from Sybase. Is it at all possible to have an Sybase database "listen" for changes in a table and when a certain condition is met to send a specific PUT request to an API?

I have looked through the "infocenter.sybase.com" documentation for Sybase but I really cannot make heads or tails of Sybase's API capabilites. Is Sybase capable of this functionality and if so where could I start?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xp_cmdshell to call externally to an OS procedure (http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36273_1251/html/sprocs/X20958.htm) but quite frankly most companies block its use as a security risk so it will depend on your own policies.

As a rule of thumb though it's usually preferable for your app to poll the table(s) for the change and act on the changes rather than expect the database to push an action back to an application layer.